# Domain and Range Notation

Tags: number-theory

I'm doing homework for my Number Theory class and the professor uses a notation that I am not familiar with.

An example problem says:
Consider the function $f(x)=x^2-1$. Express the function as a relation, and find the domain and range.

The answer to this question is $\{(x,x^2-1)|x\in\Bbb R\}$

I have to use the same notation to express the domain and range of $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-1}+1$.

By the domain convention, I know that $2x$ must be greater than or equal to $1$ for the domain, and that the range is defined by where $x$ is defined. How would I write this using this notation?

Answer (score -1):

I propose the frequently used notation: the domain is denoted by $\text{dom}$ while the range is $\text{rng}$. For the 2nd function we have $\text{dom}(f)=\left(\frac{1}{2},+\infty\right)$ and $\text{rng}(f)=\left[0,+\infty\right)$.